# EditText: Edittext is not showing below spinner

Tags: android

I have used spinner and below that i have used text view and edit text but its not showing when i run the application.. I am not getting why its not showing on emulator. Also i have declared  edittext in .java then also the edittext is not showing..I think it is bcoz of spinner. Anybody know why this is happening?

Here is the my full .xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_navbar_susa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/navigation"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/string_subscription"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_susa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5pt"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo_image"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_transparent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_navbar_susa"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:text="@string/string_startDate_susa" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
    android:layout_width="150sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
    android:background="@drawable/subscription_textarea_gray"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:focusable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="@string/string_endDate_susa" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
    android:layout_width="150sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
    android:background="@drawable/subscription_textarea_gray"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp" 
    android:focusable="false"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_type_susa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
    android:layout_marginTop="38sp"
    android:text="@string/string_subscription_type" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_amount_susa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_type_susa"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
    android:layout_marginTop="230sp"
    android:text="@string/string_amount_susa" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_amount_susa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_amount_susa"
    android:background="@drawable/subscription_textarea_gray"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:inputType="number" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what's the full contents of your xml?

Comment: it's something wrong with the RelativeLayout values you are using I mean like `layout_alignTop` put all these stuff in `LinearLayout` they are going to show.

Comment: another hypothesis remove all attributes that are related to leftOf, rightOf...etc

Comment: give me your all layout

Comment: For eg: there are textview1 edittext1 textview2 edittext2 textview3 spinner3 textview4 edittext4 and a button...I have used customized spinner. Here button is showing on emulator but textview4 and edittext4 is not showing..

Comment: what is `textView_endDate_susa`and `editText_endDate_susa` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have "layout_below", so I suppose you are using a RelaviteLayout, if true you need to add:

android:layout_below="@+id/textView_amount_susa"

in your EditText.

If not true post the full xml file.

Comment: The problem is in your android:layout_marginTop="230sp". Is really too much, try with 20 or 30 and see the result.

Comment: i know its too much but when i was using 20 or 30sp it overlapped with other. So i used error and trial method. By the way i have used scrollbar in this layout and the edittext below spinner is showing now. Why this is so? Do you know the reason?

Comment: Maybe it's because the ScrollView allow you to draw the whole layout and scroll to reach the zone which is outer the screen.

Comment: Do you know when we get classcastexception?

Comment: When you try to use a layout object like an EditText in the code declaring it like a different object like a TextView. But i think this is another question if you have solved this one.

Comment: No i am getting this problem now..Thanks by d way

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_navbar_susa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/string_subscription"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_susa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5pt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_navbar_susa"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo_image"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_navbar_susa"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_navbar_susa"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:text="@string/string_startDate_susa" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
        android:background="@drawable/subscription_textarea_gray"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_startDate_susa"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
        android:text="@string/string_endDate_susa" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText_startDate_susa"
        android:background="@drawable/subscription_textarea_gray"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp" 
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_type_susa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_marginTop="38sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
        android:text="@string/string_subscription_type" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText_endDate_susa"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_type_susa"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_amount_susa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_type_susa"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
        android:layout_marginTop="230sp"
        android:text="@string/string_amount_susa" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_amount_susa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_amount_susa"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner_type_susa"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_amount_susa"
        android:background="@drawable/subscription_textarea_gray"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:inputType="number" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

you can use like this , or you can use Linear layout and set orientation vertical, or if u want set layout at different position please send wireframe, what kind of layout you want